# Display bootstrap modal only for mobile and not for desktop

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a nasty problem regarding bootstrap modals on mobile vs desktop.

so the question will be short:

How can I `disable bootstrap modal on desktop` and enable only for mobile/tablets?

**[Here is a small js for tests:](http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/26/)**

Comment: Do you want to disable specific modal or all of them? What should happen on desktop if there is a modal (on click on some link/button, for example)?

Comment: @Dekel specific modal, of course :)    On desktop I have an hover effect that bring me in front some links that will redirect and no need for modal, but on mobile I want to open an modal.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to check if you are on mobile. You can [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser).

In this example I just used the `width` of the screen and based on it decided if to show the modal or not:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  if (window.innerWidth < 800) {
    return e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

Here is the update to your jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/28/

Comment: This in not an option actually, because if you will resize the desktop browser you'll get the modal ...

Comment: Correct, note that I said in this specific example I used the width. I also gave a link to other options of how to check if we are in mobile (using javascript). You can use any of them :)

Comment: btw, the `md/lg` classes by bootstrap works the same.... they are width-based (and not real mobile-based).

Comment: @RulerNature, did you see my comment? Did you check the link? I can update it inside the answer if you want...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**responsive utilities**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) classes. In your case you should use `.hidden-md` or `.hidden-md` class in modal box

```
<div class="modal fade hidden-lg hidden-md" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

U can use .hidden-lg class in the html. Check the below code it will hide the div in large devices.
 reference - [Bootstrap Responsive Utilities](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_helpers.asp)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/27/)

```
<div class="panel panel-warning hidden-lg" id="mymodal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  <div class="panel-body">
  <h3>click on panel to open the modal</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade hidden-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
    ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is based on width so again, that is not an option if you will resize browser on desktop.

Comment: Check this question this may help you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841543/hiding-div-if-using-mobile-browser